How to reuse typescript types and utils functions between react and react native projects
We recently started working on react-native app to replicate the react website we have. Both React and react native consumes the same API so, the payload and the responses are just going to be the same and will always be in the future as well.
We have typescript types declared in our react project and they are across hundreds of files. Re-defining these types for React Native project is time consuming and hard to maintain. What is the best way to share the typescript types and maybe other utils functions across React and React Native projects.
Setting up the mono repo is not worth the effort for us as of now. So, we have excluded this option. Appreciate your help, thanks

Create a npm package and move existing types there. Then use the package in both React and React Native applications.
{
  "name": "x api",
...
  "main": "./lib/main.js",
  "types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
}

See Publishing for the details.
